# Flip Boxes won't work on Mac, but are working on phones

Tags: html, css, macos

I thought I had everything covered, but I'm now having issues with flip boxes working on Mac.  I was able to make them compatible with different browsers on phones.  I had someone with a Mac say that they were having problems with the animation.  I heard that they saw a weird blinking and can see the front of the card through the back.  I'm not sure what I'm missing.  The last time I had this issue was with iOS, but I was just missing one line of code.  Any suggestions?  Honestly, I'm winging this as I go and can use any guidance.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  /* black */
  overflow-y: hidden;
  /* Hide vertical scrollbar */
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* Hide horizontal scrollbar */
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  /*Desktop*/
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 8fr);
  }
}

.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 275px;
  height: 250px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  border-style: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: black;
  color: #152939;
  text-align: center;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #152939;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  line-height: 1.25;
}

li {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.vertical-center {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

img {
  opacity: 0.45;
}
```

```html
<link href=https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,700,900|Ubuntu:400,500,700 rel="stylesheet">
<section id="team">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="grid">
      <!-- #stakeholder benefits -->
      <!-- #regulatory agencies -->

      <div class="flip-card">
        <div class="flip-card-inner">
          <div class="flip-card-front">
            <div class="container">
              <img src="https://i.ibb.co/26CVgtv/EMA-building-1024px.png" alt="EMA-building-1024px" border="0" width="275px" height="250px" opacity="0.4">
              <h2 class="centered">Regulatory<br />Agencies</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flip-card-back">
            <div class="vertical-center">
              <ul>
                <br />
                <li style="font-size:15px;">Real-time monitoring & auditing</li>
                <li style="font-size:15px;">No need to go on-site to &ensp; review necessary paperwork</li>
                <li style="font-size:15px;">Access to digital database on contamination levels, origin and destination(s)</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- #generators -->
      <div class="flip-card">
        <div class="flip-card-inner">
          <div class="flip-card-front">
            <div class="container">
              <img src="https://i.ibb.co/vqw9456/ba2679-3a022e1d9d7946beaf7e22d07.png" alt="ba2679-3a022e1d9d7946beaf7e22d07" border="0" width="275px" height="250px">
              <h2 class="centered">Generators</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flip-card-back">
            <div class="vertical-center">
              <ul>
                <br />
                <li style="font-size:15px;">Access to real-time project updates</li>
                <li style="font-size:15px;">Limit exposure to regulatory penalties</li>
                <li style="font-size:15px;">Accurately forecast and &ensp; reduce costs with start-to-finish project insights</li>
                <li style="font-size:15px;">Cost-effective</li>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- #environmental consultants -->
      <div class="flip-card">
        <div class="flip-card-inner">
          <div class="flip-card-front">
            <div class="container">
              <img src="https://i.ibb.co/QvN3jC5/Environmental-Consultants-SESA-e1510386416577.jpg" alt="Environmental-Consultants-SESA-e1510386416577" border="0" width="275px" height="250px">
              <h2 class="centered">Environmental Consultants</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flip-card-back">
            <div class="vertical-center">
              <br />
              <ul>
                <li style="font-size:15px;">Easier vetting to review credentials of necessary companies</li>
                <li style="font-size:15px;">Single and centralized repository to access all &ensp; relevant documents</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- #remediation consultants -->
      <div class="flip-card">
        <div class="flip-card-inner">
          <div class="flip-card-front">
            <div class="container">
              <img src="https://i.ibb.co/0KxTnM9/remediation-2-722x368.jpg" alt="remediation-2-722x368" border="0" width="275px" height="250px">
              <h2 class="centered">Certified Remediation Contractors</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flip-card-back">
            <div class="vertical-center">
              <ul>
                <br />
                <li style="font-size:15px;">Digital manifests save time, space, energy and money</li>
                <li style="font-size:15px;">Improve trucker &ensp; management</li>
                <li style="font-size:15px;">Easily post jobs in need of additional compliant &ensp; &ensp; truckers</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- #remediation professionals -->
      <div class="flip-card">
        <div class="flip-card-inner">
          <div class="flip-card-front">
            <div class="container">
              <img src="https://i.ibb.co/pWkWdMx/Services-Header-REM1.jpg" alt="Services-Header-REM1" border="0" width="275px" height="250px">
              <h2 class="centered">Remediation Professionals<br />(i.e. LSRPs)</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flip-card-back">
            <div class="vertical-center">
              <ul>
                <li style="font-size:15px;">Minimize paperwork by receiving necessary documents in the cloud</li>
                <li style="font-size:15px;">Streamlined updates to Regulatory Agencies</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- #material truckers -->
      <div class="flip-card">
        <div class="flip-card-inner">
          <div class="flip-card-front">
            <div class="container">
              <img src="https://i.ibb.co/jktCcCh/construction-materials-being-transported-through-dump-truck-hauling-services.jpg" alt="construction-materials-being-transported-through-dump-truck-hauling-services" border="0" width="275px" height="250px">
              <h2 class="centered">Material Truckers</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flip-card-back">
            <div class="vertical-center">
              <br />
              <ul>
                <li style="font-size:15px;">Easier hiring process with ability to upload credentials and list references for new &ensp; jobs</li>
                <li style="font-size:15px;">Eliminates need to call for or save paper manifest receipts</li>
                <li style="font-size:15px;">Faster pay through direct invoicing</li>
                <li style="font-size:15px;">Post available trucks for hire</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- #disposal facilities -->
      <div class="flip-card">
        <div class="flip-card-inner">
          <div class="flip-card-front">
            <div class="container">
              <img src="https://i.ibb.co/BnwcyRy/construction-site-waste.jpg" alt="construction-site-waste" border="0" width="275px" height="250px">
              <h2 class="centered">Disposal Facilities</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flip-card-back">
            <div class="vertical-center">
              <br />
              <ul>
                <li style="font-size:15px;">Go green - no need to buy paper and printer cartridges &ensp; to print paper manifests</li>
                <li style="font-size:15px;">Easier manifest delivery - assign electronically to truckers ahead of time, no need to sign paper manifests at origin and destination</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- #material testing labs -->
      <div class="flip-card">
        <div class="flip-card-inner">
          <div class="flip-card-front">
            <div class="container">
              <img src="https://i.ibb.co/wckqzpt/R0cd7e9fd21b0182c7cfba5b6c278ab7a.png" alt="R0cd7e9fd21b0182c7cfba5b6c278ab7a" border="0" width="275px" height="250px">
              <h2 class="centered">Material Testing Labs</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flip-card-back">
            <div class="vertical-center">
              <ul>
                <br />
                <li style="font-size:15px;">Share results faster by integrating with TerraTrackr database</li>
                <li style="font-size:15px;">Upload testing lab results <br /> and assign a unique project <br /> ID for easy organization</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: You have a typo `justify-items: center;` instead of `justify-content: center;`

Comment: Rotating fine on a macbook pro, chrome, firefox, safari & edge (although with some weird blinking)

Comment: Thanks for catching that!  Apparently, the cards flip, but some people can still see the word on the front in reverse.  This only seems to be an issue with Macs, but I'm not sure what's missing.

Comment: Looks like your image is still coming from the front facing card, rather than being part of the backside or as a background of the card,  so the text is coming through with it. I played around for a bit, if I hide the image with backface visibility then I also lose the image

Comment: Thanks so much! I added the backface visibility and it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding backface visibility to the image and it's all good!

Answer (score 0):

Answer: `justify-content: center;`

(You had a typo)

Comment: Thanks for the catch!  I've been looking at this for so long that I didn't notice.

Comment: This isn't the problem